PyTorch noise estimator model not learning - converges to same output regardless of input
I'm implementing a simple noise estimator using PyTorch. The model consists of a few convolutional layers followed by a small fully connected network, ending with a single neuron that outputs the estimated sigma.
I'm using the PASCAL VOC Dataset, adding Gaussian noise with a sigma randomly chosen between 0.01 and 0.1 (normalized to 0-1). However, the model seems to converge very quickly and outputs the same value regardless of the input image.
To simplify, I switched to using constant-value images (170), but the problem persists. After a few epochs, the model outputs roughly the same value for any input.
I've tried various approaches:

Using MAE Loss (converges around 0.25, output always ~0.45)
Using MSE Loss (converges around 0.08, output always ~0.5)
Adjusting batch size
Adding/removing layers
Changing learning rate
Using ReLU or LeakyReLU as activation
Adding/removing activation for the last layer
Adding batch normalization
Adjusting dropout values

None of these modifications solved the issue.
What am I missing? Why isn't the model learning to estimate the noise level correctly?
My implementation
Model
class NoiseEstimator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size=3):
        super(NoiseEstimator, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size, padding=kernel_size // 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size, padding=kernel_size // 2)

        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(64 * 32 * 32, 120)  # 6*6 from image dimension
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = torch.nn.Linear(84, 10)
        self.fc4 = torch.nn.Linear(10, 1)


    def forward(self, x):

        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), (2, 2))
        x = x.view(-1, x.shape[1] * x.shape[2] * x.shape[3])
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.fc4(x)

        return x

Dataset class:
class SigmaDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, img_dir: Path = None, noise_range=(0.01, 0.1)):
        self.img_dir = img_dir
        self.noise_range = noise_range

    def __len__(self):
        return 13000

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        image = (170 * np.ones((1, 128, 128))).astype(np.uint8)
        image = torch.from_numpy(image).to(torch.float32) / 255
        sigma_value = np.random.uniform(low=self.noise_range[0], high=self.noise_range[1])
        _, height, width = image.shape
        noise = sigma_value * torch.randn((image.size()))
        noisy_image = torch.clip(image + noise, 0, 1)
        sigma_value_normalized = (sigma_value - self.noise_range[0]) / self.noise_range[1]

        return noisy_image.float(), sigma_value_normalized

Train and evaluation function:
def train_one_epoch(model, train_loader, epoch, criterion, optimizer, batch_step, train_losses):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0
    last_loss = 0
    for batch_index, (inputs, true_noise_levels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        inputs = inputs.to(device=torch.device("cuda"))
        true_noise_levels = true_noise_levels.to(device=torch.device("cuda")).float()

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, true_noise_levels.float())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()

        if (batch_index + 1) % batch_step == 0:
            last_loss = running_loss / batch_step
            train_losses.append(last_loss)
            log.info(f"batch {batch_index}/{len(train_loader)} loss: {last_loss: .4f}")
            running_loss = 0

    return last_loss, train_losses

def eval_model(model, val_loader, epoch, criterion):
    log.info("Start evaluation")
    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0.0
    with torch.no_grad():
        random_index = random.randint(0, len(val_loader) - 1)
        for i, (inputs, true_noise_levels) in enumerate(tqdm(val_loader)):
            inputs = inputs.to(device=torch.device("cuda"))  # Move inputs to GPU
            true_noise_levels = true_noise_levels.to(device=torch.device("cuda")).float()
            outputs = model(inputs) # The input tensors are now on the same device as the model weights
            loss = criterion(outputs, true_noise_levels)
            val_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
    val_loss /= len(val_loader.dataset)
    return val_loss

Training loop
noise_range = (0.01, 0.1)
learning_rate = 0.0001
batch_size = 128

training_set = SigmaDataset(Path("train/images"), noise_range)
validation_set = SigmaDataset(Path("valid/images"), noise_range)
train_loader = DataLoader(training_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(validation_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

model = NoiseEstimator(kernel_size=5)
model = model.to(device=torch.device("cuda"))

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

best_val_loss = float('inf')

train_losses = []
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    log.info(f"Starting epoch {epoch+1}")
    train_loss, train_losses = train_one_epoch(model, train_loader, epoch, criterion, optimizer, batch_step, train_losses)

    val_loss = eval_model(model, val_loader, epoch, criterion)

    log.info(
        f"Epoch [{epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}], "
        f"Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, "
        f"Validation Loss: {val_loss:.4f}"
    )


The problem is due to broadcasting in your loss function.
Your model output is of shape (bs, 1). Your target is of shape (bs,).
The extra dimension on the model output causes the unit axis to be broadcast along the target. This means that when your loss function computes output - target, instead of getting a result of shape (bs), you get a result of shape (bs, bs). The loss from all targets is applied to all items in the batch.
As a result, the model learns to guess the average target in the batch. This is why all the outputs converge to roughly the same value.
This broadcasting error is common enough that it comes with a warning message. You probably saw this printed from your code:
UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([128])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([128, 1])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
The solution is to make the output and target have the same shape. You can do this two ways:
loss = criterion(outputs, true_noise_levels.unsqueeze(1))
loss = criterion(outputs.squeeze(), true_noise_levels)

Thank you very much for your help! Seems that my model is now learning. I should take more account of warnings in the future (I'd love to upvote, but can't because I'm new). So again thank you

@AdlaneLadjal you can also accept an answer; take the tour.
